# discord.js "messageReactionAdd" event listener not responding

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js

Whenever I react to a message, the discord bot does not log in the console that a message has been reacted to, I tried following the guide for this, it still won't work.

My current code:

```
  const axios = require('axios');
  const express = require("express")
  const app = express()
  const discord = require("discord.js")
  const { EmbedBuilder } = require('discord.js')
  const { PermissionBitField } = require("discord.js")
  const fetch = require('node-fetch');
  const fs = require('node:fs');
  const path = require('node:path');
  const { REST } = require('@discordjs/rest');
  const { Routes } = require('discord-api-types/v9');
  const rest = new REST({ version: '9' }).setToken(process.env.token);
  const { ActionRowBuilder, ButtonBuilder, ButtonStyle, SlashCommandBuilder } = require('discord.js');
  const { Collection, Events } = require('discord.js')
  const { Client, GatewayIntentBits } = require('discord.js')
  const client = new Client({
    intents: [GatewayIntentBits.Guilds, GatewayIntentBits.GuildVoiceStates, GatewayIntentBits.GuildMessages,
    GatewayIntentBits.GuildMembers,
    GatewayIntentBits.MessageContent]
  })

  app.get("/", (req, res) => {
    res.send("ModLock")
  })

  app.listen(3000, () => {
    console.clear()
    console.log(`Connecting to bot...`)
  })

  client.on('ready', async () => {
    client.user.setActivity('v0.1')
    let bot = client.user.username
    console.log(`${bot} is running!`)
  })
  
client.on('messageReactionAdd', (reaction, user) => {
  console.log("reacted")
})
  
  client.on('interactionCreate', async (interaction) => {
    if (!interaction.isCommand()) return;
    const { commandName } = interaction;
    if (commandName === 'ping') {
      await interaction.reply(`My ping is ${client.ws.ping}!`);
    }
  })

client.on('messageCreate', async (message) => {
  if(!message.author.bot){
  const report = new ButtonBuilder()
            .setCustomId(`${message.id}`)
            .setLabel('Report Message')
            .setStyle(ButtonStyle.Danger);
  const row = new ActionRowBuilder()
            .addComponents(report);
  await message.channel.send({
            components: [row],
        });
  }
})

  client.on('interactionCreate', async interaction => {
  if (interaction.isButton()) {
const channelId = interaction.channel.id
const messageId = interaction.customId
client.channels.fetch(channelId).then(channel => {
channel.messages.fetch(messageId).then(message => {
        message.delete();
    });
});
  interaction.reply({ content: `Message reported`, ephemeral: true });
    interaction.message.delete()
  } else {
  }
});

  
  const commands = [
    new SlashCommandBuilder().setName('ping').setDescription('Sends my ping.'),
  ].map(command => command.toJSON());

  (async () => {
    try {
      console.log('Started refreshing application (/) commands.');
      await rest.put(
        Routes.applicationCommands(process.env.clientId),
        { body: commands },
      );

      console.log('Successfully reloaded application (/) commands.');
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
    }
  })();

  client.login(process.env.token)
```

I know that the event only works for cached message, but even with message that are cached, when a reaction is added, the event still refuses to fire.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the `GuildMessageReactions` intent:

```js
const client = new Client({
    intents: [
        GatewayIntentBits.Guilds,
        GatewayIntentBits.GuildVoiceStates,
        GatewayIntentBits.GuildMessages,
        GatewayIntentBits.GuildMembers,
        GatewayIntentBits.MessageContent,
        GatewayIntentBits.GuildMessageReactions // Missing intent
    ]
  })
```

If you want your bot to fire on non cached messages aswell, you will need to provide the `Message`, `Channel` and `Reaction` partials.

```js
const { Partials } = require("discord.js");

const client = new Client({
    intents: [
        // ...
    ],
    // For non cached messages:
    partials: [Partials.Message, Partials.Channel, Partials.Reaction],
  })
```